# Qt QObject::connect receiver and slot of different classes

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-signals, qt-slot

I have two classes: first one is the main QMainWindow class, and the second one is my custom class. For example, I want to make a connection in the constructor of my custom class where when I press a TestButton (which is a part of the ui of main class), it calls a function from my custom class.
Here are code:

Program.h:

```
class Custom;

class Program : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    friend class Custom;

public:
    Program(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Program();

private:
    Ui::ProgramClass ui;
}
```

Program.cpp:

```
#include "Program.h"
#include "Custom.h"

Program::Program(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi

    Custom custom = Custom(this);
}
```

Custom.h:

```
#include "Program.h"

class Custom : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Custom(Program* program);
    ~Custom();

public slots:
    void foo();

private:
    Program* m_program;
}
```

and finally Custom.cpp:

```
#include "Custom.h"
#include "Program.h"

Custom::Custom(Program* program) {
    m_program = program;

    /* Here's the main problem */
    QObject::connect(m_program->ui.TestButton, &QPushButton::clicked, m_program, &Custom::foo);
}

/* Here just changing text of the button and set flat true or false every time button is clicked */
void Custom::foo() {
    QPushButton* button = m_program->ui.TestButton;

    button->setFlat(!button->isFlat());
    button->setText(button->isFlat() ?
        "If you see the text changing when clicking the button, it means test is working correctly" :
        "Text changed");
}
```

The main part is in the Custom constructor, where I typed connect function.
Error: cannot convert argument 3 from 'Program *' to 'const Custom *.
So, a pointer to receiver and to function `foo` must be the same classes.

So I tried this:
`QObject::connect(m_program->ui.TestButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Custom::foo);`

No error, but there is actually no connection to the main program and when I click the button - nothing changing.

The only working variants are:

- make `foo` function as a method of Program class, BUT I don't want to make Program class have a lot of functions which are actually should be methods of separated classes. And if I want to modify some other fields of these separated classes, this variant won't work;
- type lambda-function inside QObject::connection, BUT I have some big functions, and I need to call some of them as a slot in QObject::connect oftently.

So, how can I make a proper connection to the whole program but leave `foo` function as the method of Custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line  `Custom custom = Custom(this);` creates a local object which "dies immediately" after exit from `Program` constructor, that's not what you want to do. This is what you have to do for an instance of `Custom` to persist:

```
 Custom *custom = new Custom(this);
```

You can even make pointer named `custom` a member variable if you want access it later. The constructor of `Custom` must be:

```
 Custom::Custom(Program* program) : QObject(program) 
 {
     QObject::connect( m_program->ui.TestButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
                       this, &Custom::foo );
 }
```

This constructor passes pointer to constructor of `QObject`, which registers `Custom` as a "child" of provided object, a `Program` in our case. In Qt terms `Program` will be responsible for `Custom` instance's destruction.

Is what you meant to do? To connect a button to an instance of `Custom`? Frankly, using `m_program->ui.TestButton` here invades `Program`s personal space and relies on implementation, but it's an offtopic here.

But let's make a step aside and take a look why actually what you did, even if that was utterly wrong, didn't work?

Let's put aside functions and slots. What you'd do if had to do  this with "normal" classes and to call a method `foo()` of class `B` using a pointer of distinct `class A`?

Right, class `B` should be derived from `A` and `foo()` should be a virtual method first declared in `A`. THis allows a kind of type erasure where  a pointer  or reference to B can be passed as pointer to A. Functions can be passed by pointer too, but not if they are members of a class. For that a special kind of pointer exist.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Hello from foo()!\n"; }
};

// A registering\calling class
class C {
public:

   void connect(A* p) {  
         cptr = p;
         f_ptr = &A::foo;
   }

   void call() {  (cptr->*f_ptr)(); }
private:
   A    *cptr;
   void (A::*f_ptr)();
};

int main() {
    B  b;
    C  c;
    c.connect(&b);
    c.call();
}
```

Now, you must understand what `C::connect` does there: it saves value of pointer to the object `A* p` and a pointer to the member. The expression `&A::foo`, a pointer to a member of A, is legal and correct for overridden `&B::foo` if we will use it with a pointer to `B`.

The pointer-to-member could be made a parameter of `C::connect` like  in Qt, but to make it work with any member function we need to create a template and another level of type erasure to save those values. I left it out for brevity.

It's almost same what happens with Qt signal\slot system, at least if you use direct connection and new connect syntax. You *need* a class instance in order to call its member, that's why `connect` got such syntax. Even if you had succeed in performing connection, you would have invoked an Undefined Behavior by clicking connected button. Thankfully, Qt handles it gracefully by disconnecting destroyed objects, *therefore nothing actually happens.*

That's why all classes that use signal\slot have to be descendants of `QObject`. Signals and slots are just functions. The difference between them is that meta object compiler generates an implementation for signals.

For type erasure to work, you can do either of those:

1. have to pass a pointer of type `QObject*` to an instance of `Custom` and cast it to `class Custom` in order for `QObject::connect` to work. The cast is unnecessary if signal or *virtual* slot is declared in `QObject`.
2. Or you have to pass a pointer to some base class which already got the slot `void foo()` declared.

*You can declare a slot as virtual* and you *don't* need to do so for signals.

```
public slots:
    virtual void foo();  // can be pure in abstract class
```

It appears to me that to have a `QMainWindow` as a base class is a bad idea, you'd needs some third class. In simplest cases it creates too verbose code and that's why another overload was introduced, which allows a lambda or functor object.